# How to get a thumbnail or snapshot of a youtube video at a specific "second" with Youtube javascript API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to take a thumbnail image of a youtube video, let's say http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffaTjpA1scI at 30s or 120s. How can I do that with youtube API?

I do think this is possible, because when I watch a Youtube video, if I move my cursor to the timeline, I can immediately see snapshots at specific time. I just want to retrieve these snapshots programmatically.

I also tried http://img.youtube.com/vi//0.jpg, actually this can get the thumbnail of course, but it cannot get a snapshots at a specific time.

Answer (score 4):

Those specific type thumbnails (used for the timeline snapshots) are not exposed via any sort of official URL scheme or API. I wouldn't recommend trying to reverse-engineer a solution, either.

Comment: ok, but i really need them. It seems that https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg can take snapshots of a video at specific time. This requires deploying the video on my own server, I guess.

Comment: @JeffPosnick would reverse-engineering a solution be considered breaking the YouTube API agreement and/or deemed DMCA illegal?

Comment: @nan Is it available now?

Comment: and @bouncingHippo did you find any solution?