# Does the youtube api allow me to download screenshots of videos

Tags: youtube-api

Does the youtube api allow me to download screenshots of videos? The TOS says I can't store AV content but the initial screenshot image is just to save calls/resources for specific videos.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25144716/2274530

Comment: possible duplicate of [capturing thumbnail image at specific timeframe from youtube link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140664/capturing-thumbnail-image-at-specific-timeframe-from-youtube-link)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api

Answer (score 2):

I'm using:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoId}/1.jpg

also works 2.jpg, 3.jpg